# Specified cast is not valid. C# WebBrowser

Tags: c#, exception, browser

```
url="https://ipv4.google.com/sorry/IndexRedirect?continue=https://www.google.com/search%3Fq%3Dstackoverflow%2B%26rlz%3D1C1KMZB_enTR561TR561%26oq%3Dstac%26aqs%3Dchrome.1.69i59l3j69i60j69i57j69i60.5208j0j7%26sourceid%3Dchrome%26espv%3D210%26es_sm%3D122%26ie%3DUTF-8";

webBrowser1.Navigate(url);

if (url.Contains("ipv4.google.com"))
{
    frm2.ShowDialog();
    Application.DoEvents();
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("captcha").SetAttribute("value", frm2.code);
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click");
}
```

Exception is:

> Specified cast is not valid.

at

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("captcha").SetAttribute("value", frm2.code);
```

Comment: What is the type of frm2.Code? string?

Comment: Yes Form2  public string code = "";
code = textBox1.Text;

Comment: Whatever problem you think the line "Application.DoEvents();" fixed... it did not. It just hid the symptoms, the problem is still there. Remove that line and handle the problem properly.

Comment: Uninstall but the same :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the document when it is ready loading.

```
string url = "https://ipv4.google.com/sorry/IndexRedirect?continue=https://www.google.com/search%3Fq%3Dstackoverflow%2B%26rlz%3D1C1KMZB_enTR561TR561%26oq%3Dstac%26aqs%3Dchrome.1.69i59l3j69i60j69i57j69i60.5208j0j7%26sourceid%3Dchrome%26espv%3D210%26es_sm%3D122%26ie%3DUTF-8";

WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
this.Controls.Add(webBrowser1);
webBrowser1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

webBrowser1.Navigate(url);

if (url.Contains("ipv4.google.com"))
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += handler;
}

private void handler(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        frm2.ShowDialog();
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("captcha").SetAttribute("value", frm2.code);
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click");

        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= handler;
    };
```

Comment: problem Webbrowser Document  "Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation."  writes

Comment: doc = null element = null :((

Comment: On which line? Still the `webBrowser.Document`?

Comment: The image you send is not an error, it is 'just' Visual Studio having trouble to evaluate the properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your webBrowser1 doesn't have the document loaded at the moment when you try to access it. You should put your code in the if-clause into the eventhandler for `webBrowser1.Navigate`. At this moment the webBrowser has fully loaded the document behind the url

Comment: Can you give example?